# Can scalar functions be applied before filtering when executing a SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, scalar

I suppose I have always naively assumed that scalar functions in the select part of a SQL query will only get applied to the rows that meet all the criteria of the where clause.

Today I was debugging some code from a vendor and had that assumption challenged.  The only reason I can think of for this code failing is that the Substring() function is getting called on data that should have been filtered out by the WHERE clause.  But it appears that the substring call is being applied before the filtering happens, the query is failing.
Here is an example of what I mean.  Let's say we have two tables, each with 2 columns and having 2 rows and 1 row respectively.  The first column in each is just an id.  NAME is just a string, and NAME_LENGTH tells us how many characters in the name with the same ID.  Note that only names with more than one character have a corresponding row in the LONG_NAMES table.

```
NAMES: ID, NAME
    1, "Peter"
    2, "X"
LONG_NAMES: ID, NAME_LENGTH
    1, 5
```

If I want a query to print each name with the last 3 letters cut off, I might first try something like this (assuming SQL Server syntax for now):

```
SELECT substring(NAME,1,len(NAME)-3)
    FROM NAMES;
```

I would soon find out that this would give me an error, because when it reaches "X" it will try using a negative number for in the substring call, and it will fail.
The way my vendor decided to solve this was by filtering out rows where the strings were too short for the len - 3 query to work.  He did it by joining to another table:

```
SELECT substring(NAMES.NAME,1,len(NAMES.NAME)-3) 
    FROM NAMES 
        INNER JOIN LONG_NAMES 
            ON NAMES.ID = LONG_NAMES.ID;
```

At first glance, this query looks like it might work.  The join condition will eliminate any rows that have NAME fields short enough for the substring call to fail.

However, from what I can observe, SQL Server will sometimes try to calculate the the substring expression for everything in the table, and *then* apply the join to filter out rows.  Is this supposed to happen this way?  Is there a documented order of operations where I can find out when certain things will happen?  Is it specific to a particular Database engine or part of the SQL standard?  If I decided to include some predicate on my NAMES table to filter out short names, (like len(NAME) > 3), could SQL Server also choose to apply that after trying to apply the substring?  If so then it seems the only safe way to do a substring would be to wrap it in a "case when" construct in the select?

Comment: Yep. `CASE ` is the only safe way of doing this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191701/tsql-divide-by-zero-encountered-despite-no-columns-containing-0/5203211#5203211 for a  good answer on this topic.

Comment: @Martin thanks for the link.  I couldn't figure out how to search for similar questions to this one as it is kind of abstract.

Answer (score 2):

Martin gave this link that pretty much explains what is going on - the query optimizer has free rein to reorder things however it likes.  I am including this as an answer so I can accept something.  Martin, if you create an answer with your link in it i will gladly accept that instead of this one.

I do want to leave my question here because I think it is a tricky one to search for, and my particular phrasing of the issue may be easier for someone else to find in the future.

[TSQL divide by zero encountered despite no columns containing 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191701/tsql-divide-by-zero-encountered-despite-no-columns-containing-0/5203211#5203211)

EDIT:  As more responses have come in, I am again confused.  It does not seem clear yet when exactly the optimizer is allowed to evaluate things in the select clause.  I guess I'll have to go find the SQL standard myself and see if i can make sense of it.

Comment: A dbms that conforms to SQL standards has *some* freedom to reorder things, but it doesn't have free rein to reorder things just however it likes. It's still required to produce the same results as an unoptimized, brute force, step-by-step, pencil-and-paper evaluation of the query. And in this case, I'm pretty sure that means it has to act like it evaluates the WHERE clause before it evaluates the SELECT clause. (See my answer with references somewhere around here.)

Comment: @Catcall - This has been raised in the Microsoft Connect Site before. See https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors

Comment: I think I'd rather have said "it has free rein to reorder things  however it likes as long as it still produces the same result as an unoptimized, brute force, step-by-step, pencil-and-paper evaluation of the same query".

Answer (score 1):

Joe Celko, who helped write early SQL standards, has posted something similar to this several times in various USENET newsfroups. (I'm skipping over the clauses that don't apply to your SELECT statement.) He usually said something like "This is how statements are supposed to act like they work". In other words, SQL implementations should behave exactly as if they did these steps, without actually being required to do each of these steps.

1. Build a working table from all of
   the table constructors in the FROM
   clause.
2. Remove from the working table those
   rows that do not satisfy the WHERE
   clause.
3. Construct the expressions in the
   SELECT clause against the working table.

So, following this, no SQL dbms should act like it evaluates functions in the SELECT clause before it acts like it applies the WHERE clause.

In a recent posting, [Joe expands the steps to include CTEs](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1053018-392-1.aspx).

CJ Date and Hugh Darwen say essentially the same thing in chapter 11 ("Table Expressions") of their book *A Guide to the SQL Standard*. They also note that this chapter corresponds to the "Query Specification" section (sections?) in the SQL standards.

Comment: Are joins considered part of the where clause or a separate phase?

Comment: In the stuff I read, JOIN clauses were considered one of many "table constructors in the FROM clause".

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about something called query execution plan. It's based on query optimization rules, indexes, temporaty buffers and execution time statistics. If you are using SQL Managment Studio you have toolbox over your query editor where you can look at estimated execution plan, it shows how your query will change to gain some speed. So if just used your Name table and it is in buffer, engine might first try to subquery your data, and then join it with other table.