# SQL query and join: why?

Tags: sql, join

I'm sorry if this is a newbie question, but it seems I don't get why this doesn't work like I would like:

```
mysql> select t.id,t.date_fin_val,tc.date_fin_val
from tiers t
join tiers_critere_int tc on tc.id_tiers=t.id
where (t.date_fin_val is null) and (tc.date_fin_val is null);
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | date_fin_val        | date_fin_val        |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
|  1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
|  1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select t.id,t.date_fin_val,tc.date_fin_val
from tiers t
left outer join tiers_critere_int tc on tc.id_tiers=t.id
where (t.date_fin_val is null) and (tc.date_fin_val is null);
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I thought that "left outer joins" means: "if there is no result on the right side, but one on the left, go on **anyway** with the one on the left and put "`null`" values on the right.
If I were right, the  second query with "`left outer join`" instead of "`join`" should return values. But it doesn't. Why?

Here are my datas:

```
mysql> select * from tiers t where date_fin_val is null;
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
| id | date_fin_val        | est_tiers_physique |
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                  1 | 
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tiers_critere_int  where date_fin_val is null;
+----+---------------------+----------+------------+---------+
| id | date_fin_val        | id_tiers | id_critere | critere |
+----+---------------------+----------+------------+---------+
|  1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |        1 |          2 |      86 |
|  2 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |        1 |          6 |     170 |
|  3 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |        1 |          7 |      65 |
+----+---------------------+----------+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you mean to say that the *second* query doesn't return values?

Comment: I'm confused as to how the first query is returning results.  In the where clause, you indicate that BOTH date values need to be null, but in the result set neither date value is null.  The queries should return the same thing regardless of join or left join .. you shouldn't get less results with a left join, only more if the corresponding fields in the right table are null.

Comment: Show us what kind of data exists in tables tiers and tiers_critere_int (with id 1).

Comment: @Tandu If a `datetime` is `null` then MySQL returns `"0000-00-00 00:00:00"`. Thus the results you see. Anyway I've added the data that are in my tables in my question.

Comment: @OlivierDofus as far as I know this is untrue and it will return null.  I ran the query myself and got no results.

Comment: It does return results (otherwise I wouldn't have asked my question here =D ). Maybe it's the MySQL version? Mine is 5.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My results are correct with you data and queries.

```
CREATE TABLE `tiers` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_fin_val` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `est_tiers_physique` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

insert into tiers (id, est_tiers_physique) values (1, 1);

select * from tiers;
+------+--------------+--------------------+
| id   | date_fin_val | est_tiers_physique |
+------+--------------+--------------------+
|    1 | NULL         |                  1 |
+------+--------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

CREATE TABLE `tiers_critere_int` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_fin_val` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_tiers` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_critere` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `critere` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

insert into tiers_critere_int (id, id_tiers, id_critere, critere) 
values 
(1, 1, 2, 86),
(2, 1, 6, 170),
(3, 1, 7, 65)
;

select * from tiers_critere_int;
+------+--------------+----------+------------+---------+
| id   | date_fin_val | id_tiers | id_critere | critere |
+------+--------------+----------+------------+---------+
|    1 | NULL         |        1 |          2 |      86 |
|    2 | NULL         |        1 |          6 |     170 |
|    3 | NULL         |        1 |          7 |      65 |
+------+--------------+----------+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select t.id,t.date_fin_val,tc.date_fin_val
from tiers t
join tiers_critere_int tc on tc.id_tiers=t.id
where (t.date_fin_val is null) and (tc.date_fin_val is null);
+------+--------------+--------------+
| id   | date_fin_val | date_fin_val |
+------+--------------+--------------+
|    1 | NULL         | NULL         |
|    1 | NULL         | NULL         |
|    1 | NULL         | NULL         |
+------+--------------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select t.id,t.date_fin_val,tc.date_fin_val
from tiers t
left outer join tiers_critere_int tc on tc.id_tiers=t.id
where (t.date_fin_val is null) and (tc.date_fin_val is null);
+------+--------------+--------------+
| id   | date_fin_val | date_fin_val |
+------+--------------+--------------+
|    1 | NULL         | NULL         |
|    1 | NULL         | NULL         |
|    1 | NULL         | NULL         |
+------+--------------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Now if you insert an empty string you will have:

```
insert into tiers (id, date_fin_val, est_tiers_physique) values (2, '', 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

select * from tiers;
+------+---------------------+--------------------+
| id   | date_fin_val        | est_tiers_physique |
+------+---------------------+--------------------+
|    1 | NULL                |                  1 |
|    2 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                  1 |
+------+---------------------+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It's a key problem, thanks for pointing this out, your example shows I was right and I properly get what "left outer join" is for :). Many thanks again. I've posted the detailed answer, and where the confusion came from.

Comment: @Olivier The real problem is that there are no nulls in you data. In instead there are empty dates

Comment: You're right. But it's a real problem for MySQL because it allows insertion of null keys (which shouldn't work), it allows select for null values on keys (which should *always* return an empty result), and sometimes it works (see my#1 query in my question), sometimes it doesn't work (see my#2 query in my question). This is by far too confusing. I've lost 4 hours trying to sort this out. I've even re-checked that my comprehension of "left outer join" was right (and all the answers here confirmed I was right)

Comment: Sorry it took me a long time to validate your answer =)

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's a bug in MySQL.
Here's how I created my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tiers_critere_int (
  id bigint AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  date_debut_val datetime not null,
  date_fin_val datetime **default NULL**,
  id_tiers bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  id_critere bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  critere bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id,date_debut_val,date_fin_val),
  KEY id (id),
  KEY date_debut_val (date_debut_val),
  KEY date_fin_val (date_fin_val),
  KEY date_debut_val_2 (date_debut_val,date_fin_val),
  KEY critere (critere),
  KEY id_tiers (id_tiers),
  KEY id_critere (id_critere),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_tiers) REFERENCES tiers (id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (id_critere) REFERENCES critere (id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In `tiers_critere_int`, `date_fin_val` **is null by default**.
That's what you think.
But if you do:

```
mysql> update tiers_critere_int set date_fin_val= null;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 0  Warnings: 3

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                              |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1048 | Column 'date_fin_val' cannot be null | 
| Warning | 1048 | Column 'date_fin_val' cannot be null | 
| Warning | 1048 | Column 'date_fin_val' cannot be null | 
+---------+------+--------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

The problem is that MySQL does accept the creation of the table, but does **not** accept null values for keys.
But what is not normal, is that this query works and that's clearly surprising (or not normal it's up to you to judge):

```
mysql> select * from tiers_critere_int
where date_fin_val is null;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------+------------+---------+
| id | date_debut_val      | date_fin_val        | id_tiers | id_critere | critere |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------+------------+---------+
|  1 | 2011-03-13 06:07:05 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |        1 |          2 |      86 | 
|  2 | 2011-03-13 06:07:05 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |        1 |          6 |     170 | 
|  3 | 2011-03-13 06:07:05 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |        1 |          7 |      65 | 
+----+---------------------+---------------------+----------+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

So that whas really confusing, and what was more confusing is that the clause "is null" is properly handled in the clause `where (t.date_fin_val is null)`, but it's not properly handled in the clause `and (tci.date_fin_val is null)` whereas it's in the **same** request, on tables created the **same** way, on the **same** columns.

Thus, the end of the story:
**the right request is**:

```
mysql> select t.id,t.date_fin_val,tci.date_fin_val
from tiers t
left outer join tiers_critere_int tci
on t.id=tci.id_tiers
where (t.date_fin_val ='0000-00-00 00:00:00')
and (tci.date_fin_val ='0000-00-00 00:00:00');
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | date_fin_val        | date_fin_val        |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Ah!  Keys messing things up.  Bad on MySQL to screw this up imho.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this has to do with [how MySQL optimizes LEFT (and RIGHT) JOINs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html) in combination with the date columns being NULLs.

Comment: I would think that MySQL won't optimize queries to produce incorrect results, right?

Comment: @Stephen Chung: It seems we can't always count on the people who code optimizers to get it right. Recently, in another SO question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249415/can-scalar-functions-be-applied-before-filtering-when-executing-a-sql-statement, we determined that SQL Server was incorrectly optimizing a statement and returning incorrect results. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors

Answer (score 0):

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the same condition and the same data should return *more or the same number* of rows as `INNER JOIN`.

Please check:

1. Your data to see if they are the same for the two queries
2. Whether the two queries are as you specified in the question (e.g. have you made a typo)

Comment: It seems there's a bug in MySQL (yes yes yes >_<). If I do `select * from tiers t left outer join tiers_critere_int tci on t.id=tci.id_tiers  where (tci.date_fin_val is null);` I get `Empty set (0.00 sec)` and if I try *exactly* the same request but with `where (tci.date_fin_val ='0000-00-00 00:00:00');` I get all what I need. So this is either a bug or a strange behavior.

Comment: Hhhmmmm.... it seems that MySQL might be returning `0000-00-00 00:00:00` for empty date values instead of NULL.  You probably need to check the manual to see if this behavior is documented.  It is certainly not correct SQL behavior if you ask me.

Comment: You're right, this was a key problem, but the way MySQL handles this is by far too confusing. (It has no consistant behavior: one time it works another time not).

Answer (score 0):

Woa --- I think you are all missing something:

This is the current left join:

```
mysql> select t.id,t.date_fin_val,tc.date_fin_val
from tiers t
left outer join tiers_critere_int tc on tc.id_tiers=t.id
where (t.date_fin_val is null) and (tc.date_fin_val is null);
```

The left join condition should probably be this:

```
mysql> select t.id,t.date_fin_val,tc.date_fin_val
from tiers t
left outer join tiers_critere_int tc on tc.id_tiers=t.id AND (tc.date_fin_val is null)
where (t.date_fin_val is null);
```

The fact that you were still filtering rows in the WHERE clause is hiding what you are trying to do with your LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: No, the original query would have worked if the dates were actually NULL as the OP had thought they were. It simply turned out that they were something different, which was caused by the column's being defined as a KEY. But otherwise you are right in general that adding a WHERE condition for filtering on *values* from the left side of the left outer join effectually makes the join an inner one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer this might be something I have to keep  in mind when doing "left outer joins" like this (and i'm about to do a *lot* like this)!