# Why does ISNUMERIC('.') return 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently I was working with ISNUMERIC in SQL Server, when I encountered a problem, which led to finding this snippet of code.

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('.')
```

This returns 1, as in true, shouldn't this return 0 as in false?

Comment: nope. 1.1 is numeric.   ISNUMERIC()) is very basic, one might even say dumb...hence it considers a period numeric.

Comment: for that matter ',' works too (many locales use that as the decimal divider)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See [IsNumeric() Broken? Only up to a point](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/philfactor/archive/2011/01/13/98746.aspx).

```
SELECT CAST('.' AS MONEY)
```

returns `0.00` (though the cast fails for `int` and `float`)

`ISNUMERIC` just checks that the value can be cast to any one of the numeric datatypes which is generally useless. Usually you want to know whether it can be cast to a specific type.

[Additionally it doesn't even seem to do that task correctly for all possible inputs.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/76834/3690). `ISNUMERIC(' ')` returns `0` despite casting successfully to both int and money. Conversely `ISNUMERIC(N'８')` returns `1` but does not cast successfully to anything that I tried.

Some useful helper functions for that are here [IsNumeric, IsInt, IsNumber](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/isnumeric-isint-isnumber).

SQL Server 2012 introduced [`TRY_PARSE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx) and [`TRY_CONVERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) that help with this greatly.

Comment: exactly. Consider the slippery slope: `10` is ok, `10.0` is ok, `10.` is ok... (_starting to slide_) so `.1` should be ok... and `.0` and... yes `.` is ok too. [Being generous to input parsing](https://plus.google.com/114034641416688387662/posts/8bJZnLFxAfi) has it's downsides sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for that, roll on Denali!

Comment: In my case it was returning 1 to dash input (thinking it's -1). My workaround was to prepend a '0' in the func call, like this: `ISNUMERIC('0'+input)`. This way, the func tries to parse '0-', returning 0 then.

Comment: What about this? It blows my mind.... select isnumeric('-') returns 1 as well :(

Comment: @JuanVelez - `SELECT CAST('-' AS INT) ` does return `0` so that does cast successfully to at least one number type (which is all this function checks)

Answer (score 2):

Because "." is used in a decimal number !

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)

> isnumeric for '-' & '.' Why isnumeric('-') & isnumeric('.') returning
>   1?
>
> Answer: Because "-" means negative and  "." is used in a decimal
>   number.  I have no clue why they named it ISNUMERIC though.  They
>   should have named it, ISNUMBERRELATED.

Answer (score 0):

I think it also interprets a number of other non-numeric fields as numeric, there's further info here -

http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html