# Guessing Data Type of columns stored as VarChar in SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm just wondering if anyone has created or heard of a function to guess the appropriate data type of data stored in a SQLServer table as VarChar.

I'm working on an SSIS package that you can point at a directory, and it will loop through and create tables / import data for every CSV that exists it. I'm having trouble with specifying the data types before import, so as a work around I would like to import all the data as VarChar(50) into a temporary table and then run some sort of function to analyze each column for the appropriate data type (int, decimal, float, etc) so I can use that to script the create table and insert statements.

So for example I'd like to be able to point a function or query at this temp table

```
CREATE TABLE [#Data]
(
[ProductCode] varchar(50),
[ProductName] varchar(50),
[Year] varchar(50),
[Total_volume] varchar(50),
[Total_Quantity] varchar(50),
[PercentSold] varchar(50)
)
```

to read through the data and determine what data type / length is most appropriate - much like the 'Suggest Data Type' tool in Excel Connection Manager does, only something I can tie into a variable to be done dynamically. It should end up looking something like

```
CREATE TABLE [Data]
(
[ProductCode] varchar(6),
[ProductName] varchar(11),
[Year] int,
[Total_volume] int,
[Total_Quantity] int,
[PercentSold] decimal(3,2)
)
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the built-in checks for most of this.  Something like `case when isnumeric(col1) = 1 then
   case when col1 like '%.%' then 'Decimal'
   else 'Int' end
  when ISDATE(col1) = 1 then 'Date'
  else 'Varchar'
 end`

Comment: The import/export wizard in SSMS does datatype guessing.   You could ask Microsoft for their algorithm.

Comment: The [Data Profiling Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895263.aspx) would help. If you are on Enterprise Edition.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you're going to run into data like `02116` Oh, that's a number so we'll declare it as a an int and then the fine people of Boston are going to hate you for claiming their zip code is 2116. That leading zero is significant. [IsNumeric](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7400318/181965) can return curious results. Do you know your percents won't have an actual % sign?