# SQL Server REGEX failing

Tags: sql-server, regex

Why in sql server does the below return false?

```
SELECT IIF('12345' like '\d+','True','False') as Integer
```

Comment: I guess **LIKE** does not accept regex.

Comment: In MSSQL there is isnumeric https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql .

Comment: @Rahul actually looks like `like` supports a variation of regex, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql.

Comment: @chris85: That's not a variation of regex. That's simply a set of one or more characters.

Comment: `isnumeric` is broken. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7400335/121544

Comment: @KenWhite Well I guess I should have said you can allow a range of characters like in regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LIKE` does not do regular expressions. It is a very simple pattern matching. [SQL Server is a little more powerful then the standard LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql).

`'12345' not like '%[^0123456789]%'` will match all strings that do not contain a non-numeric character. To make sure there is at least one digit `and len('123456') > 0`.

*Edit*: I forgot about character ranges which is more obviously correct, `'12345' not like '%[^0-9]%'`.

Comment: Thanks.   Weird that just doing the double negative thing makes it work

Answer (score 0):

REGEX is limited in SQL Server... you can use a few different methods. Here's one.

```
select case when patindex('%[^0-9]%','1234566') = 0 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end
```

You can also look at `ISNUMERIC()` but read this function carefully before using... it returns false positives. E.g. `SELECT ISNUMERIC($)`

Comment: SELECT PATINDEX('%\d+%','123') as Integer     will return 0

Comment: someone had said \d+ was equivalent to [0-9] .  looks like they removed that post now