# Weird T-SQL DATEADD Overflow

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to add a numeric(16,8) to a smalldatetime. I receive an overflow error which I cannot make sense of.

metric_value is the number, business_date is the smalldatetime.

```
SELECT
    rsda.name
    , business_date
    , metric_value
    , DATEADD(dd, metric_value, business_date) AS o_dt
    , metric.name
FROM [redacted] met
INNER JOIN [redacted] rsda ON met.bu_id = rsda.data_accessor_id
INNER JOIN Metric ON met.metric_id = metric.metric_id
WHERE CHARINDEX('Remodel', metric.name) > 0

Msg 517, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Adding a value to a 'smalldatetime' column caused an overflow.
```

I realize that the obvious answer is "One of your dates adds beyond year 9999" but that isn't the case here. All of the dates are in 2017, and all of the numbers are whole numbers below 100, *at least when the WHERE clause is true.*

The met table has tons of other unrelated data to my 'Remodel' criteria and I'm wondering if that could cause the error. It is a strange table but I do not have control over its design. Is it possible that part of the DATEADD process occurs before my WHERE clause is applied? I cannot imagine what else is going on.

**Edit**. When i remove the DATEADD field:

Here's the first row of 'ORDER BY business_date ASC'

```
+----------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+
|   name   |    business_date    | metric_value |    name     |
+----------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+
| 466 - 94 | 2017-03-13 00:00:00 | 59.00000000  | FullRemodel |
+----------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

ORDER BY business_date DESC

```
+----------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 440 - 87 | 2017-07-31 00:00:00 | 38.00000000 | FullRemodel |
+----------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

ORDER BY metric_value ASC

```
+----------+---------------------+------------+----------------+
| 471 - 05 | 2017-05-01 00:00:00 | 0.00000000 | PartialRemodel |
+----------+---------------------+------------+----------------+
```

ORDER BY metric_value DESC

```
+----------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 466 - 86 | 2017-03-13 00:00:00 | 59.00000000 | FullRemodel |
+----------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: smalldatetime only goes up to June 6, 2079

Comment: Ok, good to know. But none of the dates will exceed 2017 in this case.

Comment: I'd remove the DATEADD() field and look at the returned data to see if there is something unexpected in the metric_value or business_date fields.

Comment: I already did that. But I'll edit my original question with "proof"

Comment: "Is it possible that part of the DATEADD process occurs before my WHERE clause is applied? ". Yes. Same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/7192524/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith Interesting. What do you suggest in my case? Subquery? Temp table? Something more elegant than those two options?

Comment: My guess is that you have an unexpected date in your data or one of your metric_values isn't correct. SELECT out your data to see what you're working with.

Comment: A subquery isn't safe it can be pushed into there too. Use `CASE WHEN metric_value BETWEEN datediff(dd, business_date, '1900-01-01') AND datediff(dd, business_date, '2079-06-06')
THEN DATEADD(dd, metric_value, business_date) END`

Comment: Do any of your metric_value values have anything in the decimal positions, or are they all .00000000?

Comment: The error does seem to indicate that the smalldatetime is being overflowed. I'd check your metric_value fields.

Comment: Also, in your SELECT, you are pulling both rsda.name and metric.name without aliasing either one. This ends with two "name" columns. You won't be able to reference it outside of your results.

Comment: RE: My comment about decimals in metric_value. Really it doesn't matter if they have decimals. When it goes into the dateadd() function, it's truncated (not rounded) to an int anyway. So 1.99999999 will be 1, not 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that part of the DATEADD process occurs before my WHERE clause is applied?

Yes. The compute scalar calculating the expression can run on rows before they get filtered out. Some links on this topic are in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7192951/73226).

You can use a `CASE` expression to only do the dateadd if the two inputs would result in a valid date for the smalldatetime range.

```
CASE 
 WHEN metric_value BETWEEN datediff(day, business_date, '1900-01-01') 
                       AND datediff(day, business_date, '2079-06-06')
 THEN 
  DATEADD(day, metric_value, business_date) 
END
```

Comment: Thanks, and for the links in your other comment.

Comment: This is a good method to prevent the error, but, if the user has control over the data, I still think this logic should be put in the WHERE clause to find the bad row and then fix the data.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could also use (in the SELECT)

```
CASE 
  WHEN metric_value <= datediff(day, GETDATE(), '20790606') 
  THEN DATEADD(day, metric_value, business_date) 
  ELSE NULL 
END AS o_dt
```

Using BETWEEN on datetimes can get hinky, so I try to avoid it.

---

EDIT: Per Martin's comment below, I no longer consider this a valid solution.

> In combination with @Martin Smith's answer, you could also change your
>   query to a subquery, and it *should* filter out the rows that are
>   causing the error.
>
> ```
> SELECT t1.rsda_name
>     , t1.business_date
>     , t1.metric_value
>     , DATEADD(day, t1.metric_value, t1.business_date) AS o_dt
>     , t1.metric_name
> FROM (
>     SELECT
>         rsda.name AS rsda_name
>         , business_date
>         , metric_value
>         , metric.name AS metric_name
>     FROM [redacted] met
>     INNER JOIN [redacted] rsda ON met.bu_id = rsda.data_accessor_id
>     INNER JOIN Metric ON met.metric_id = metric.metric_id
>     WHERE CHARINDEX('Remodel', metric.name) > 0
> ) t1
> ```

Comment: And it might not be a bad idea to leave a comment as to why you are using 06/06/2079 as your date.

Comment: This is not a safe solution. The compute scalar can be pushed into the sub query. See https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors

Comment: @MartinSmith Interesting. Didn't know that. I'll edit my answer for future users. :-)

Comment: @MartinSmith I imagine that wasn't a fun bug to encounter. :-/

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace 'dd' with DAY whithin the DATEADD() function.

Comment: While I agree that putting DAY, YEAR, MONTH, etc in your DATEADD function, "dd" is still a perfectly valid abbreviation for "day".

Comment: Yes, the query still fails.