# How do I get Dapper to ignore invalid data?

Tags: sql-server, dapper

I'm using Dapper to load an `int?` value. The value of the `int?` is stored  in a VARCHAR column in a SQL Server database (I can't change this). Occasionally the column contains invalid data that includes alpha characters.

When this happens I see this error:

`Error parsing column 5 (Foo=ABC123 - String) ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.`

How do I get Dapper to ignore invalid values and use null instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your SQL to parse and return the value accordingly on SQL Server itself. This way, there will be no changes in your calling code.

I would do something like :

```
select case when isnumeric(foo) = 1 then foo else null end foo from table;
```

Answer (score 2):

Dapper is simple mapper; it do not do this kind of data type conversion for you. You have to do a trick.

The only (bad) option I can see is to include `string` property in your class and map dapper to that property instead of your `int?` property. Then map `int?` property to `string` property with some *handling* code in between.

```
public class MyTable
{
    public string MyColumn {get;set;}//Map dapper to this property
    public int? MyColumnInt //<-- Do NOT map this to dapper. Do not implement setter
    {
        get
        {
            int temp;
            if(int.TryParse(MyColumn, out temp) == true)
                return temp;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56972870/5779732) (from @DanB) is good but it could be improved.

If you're using a modern version of SQL Server (2012 or later) consider using `TRY_CAST` instead of `ISNUMERIC`. `ISNUMERIC` behaves in ways you might not expect. Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567804/sql-isnumeric-not-working) question.