# Getting 'Conversion failed .. for varchar value to int' if I remove ORDER BY CLAUSE

Tags: sql-server-2008, debugging

Getting a weird problem since a few days, which is preventing me from running any queries.

```
SELECT Empid as EmployeeId, EmpName,
CustomerName as 'Distributor Name', Customer.RSCode, markedFor as 'Date Marked For',
CASE WHEN Present = 0 THEN 'ABSENT' ELSE 'PRESENT' END AS Attendance, Reason
FROM EmployeeAttendance_Backup ea, Customer, Employee e, EmployeeMaster em
WHERE 
ea.DistID = cast(Customer.RSCode as int)
AND e.EmployeeMasterID=em.Id
AND ea.Empid = em.EmployeeID
--ORDER BY markedFor
```

If I run the above query, I get ~160k - 190k records, before it terminates with the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Present
>   500004862' to data type int.

I am not even selecting the field, for which it is throwing this error.

If I enable the `ORDER BY` clause, I do not get any records, and this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Hirannaiah K R' to data type int.

The EmployeeAttendance_Backup table has close to 2 lakh records. Is this causing any problems? I do not know how to look for solution. I tried going through the attendance table for this particular employee, to check if some records were incorrectly saved, but that is not the case. Did the same for Employee and EmployeeMaster for this particular employee.

Where do I start looking for problems?

Comment: Try `WHERE  ea.DistID = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Customer.RSCode) = 1 THEN Cast(Customer.RSCode AS INT) END`. Though you would be better off fixing your design so you aren't storing mixed datatypes in that column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TSQL divide by zero encountered despite no columns containing 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191701/tsql-divide-by-zero-encountered-despite-no-columns-containing-0)

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for answering. Your suggestion didnot change anything. Also, the schema is such that there are varchars where necessary and ints other place. So, The link that you provided also did not help :(

Comment: Which column is it that contains the values `'Present 500004862'` and `'Hirannaiah K R'` then? You will need to do similar where ever that column is referenced. Likely you are getting an implicit cast to `int` and your schema does seem like a mess. If you don't mix datatypes like that you won't encounter this sort of issue.

Comment: The columns are `fieldid` and `EmpName` respectively. The DB was handed down to me, so I need to get my head round the relations and schema. Not completely ruling out a messy one. I guess the fact that I need a cast itself is indicator that its not coherent.

Comment: There is no `fieldid` in the code you posted and there is nothing that would cause an implicit cast for `EmpName` either. You need to look at the values in the columns being used in the equality conditions - except for possibly if any of the tables you are referencing are in fact views? In which case you may need to run `sp_refreshview` on them. Schema changes of the underlying tables can sometimes cause this sort of odd error.

Comment: I have mentioned the field not being present in the select clause. None of the fields are from a view. I can confirm that there are datatype issues. EmpId is in one table and varchar in another. *facepalms* Thanks for the `sp_refreshview` command, I did not know about it :)