# Getting 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table called `testTable` with two columns, `id` that is auto incremented and `someValue`.

The data contained in the `someValue` column are: `12, 1.2, .4, 1d4, +, -, .`

Data type for `someValue` is `varchar(50)`.

Why are the following queries throwing

> *Error converting data type varchar to numeric.*

```
select ID, someValue 
from testTable 
where ISNUMERIC(someValue + 'd0') = 1 and CAST(someValue as decimal(8,2)) > 0.1;

select tt.ID,tt.someValue 
from (select ID, someValue 
      from testTable 
      where ISNUMERIC(someValue + 'd0') = 1) as tt 
where CAST(tt.someValue as decimal(8,2)) > 0.1;
```

Comment: Your first statement will fail since SQL Server never guarantees to evaluate the first part of the `WHERE` clause before the second ...

Comment: Ok. But what about the second query. Why is it failing too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TSQL divide by zero encountered despite no columns containing 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191701/tsql-divide-by-zero-encountered-despite-no-columns-containing-0). You would need to put the cast inside a case expression.

Comment: Your second query is failing because SQL Server never guarantees to evaluate subselects before the select. How about telling us **why** you are trying to compare things like '1d4' and '+' as decimal? What is the point?

Comment: I want to get numerical values greater that a number say 1. But the problem is the column contains both numerical and non-numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems; `CAST` does not work on non-decimal input, and `ISNUMERIC` accepts strings that can convert to monetary amounts, including non-decimal values like '-', '.', or 'US$100'.

The right way to solve this is to add a `Decimal` column to your database, have whatever populates `someValue` to populate the `Decimal` column with the value you want to compare against, and only compare against the `Decimal` column.

If, for some reason, you cannot do that, you can use `ISNUMERIC` and only include non-monetary decimal amounts, and use `Convert` instead of `CAST`:

```
select ID, someValue 
from testTable 
where ID IN
    (select ID from testTable where ISNUMERIC(someValue) = 1
    AND Patindex('%[^0-9-+.]%', someValue) = 0
    AND someValue NOT IN ('-', '+', '.')
    )
    and Convert(decimal, someValue) > 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first statement you take directly from `testTable` and attempt:

```
CAST(someValue as  decimal(8,2))
```

This will throw an error as you have not filtered out non-numerical values.

Comment: Thanks. But what about the second query? I got a table tt with numeric values in varchar. But that is also giving me error.